# bash script ... issue with sending emails based on return code of a command

Tags: shell-script

I have this script for taking postgres dump from a remote host.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

NOW=$(date +%F_%H%M%S)
DB_NAME='lafis'
DB_USER='postgres'
SOURCE='rd1397.rz-dvz.cn-mv.net'
DUMPDIR='/opt/db/export/postgres/dumps'
DUMPFILE="${DB_NAME}"_LaFIS_dump_prod_rd1397.dmp
EMAIL_TO='recipient1@mycompany.co,recipient2@mycompany.co'
MIN_SPACE='46'

# check whether the dump_dir has minimum 51GiB free space
# stop execution, if not
if [ "$(df -h ${DUMPDIR} | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}' | sed 's/G//g')" -le "${MIN_SPACE}" ] ; then
   # hecho ; echo "   less then ${MIN_SPACE} GiB available @${DUMPDIR}. Stopping the dump for DB ${DB_NAME} now." ; echo
   echo ; echo "   less then ${MIN_SPACE} GiB available @${DUMPDIR}. Stopping the dump for DB ${DB_NAME} now." | \
   mailx -s [postgres@"${HOSTNAME}"]: ERROR: LaFIS_Dump_Erstellung_Ref "${EMAIL_TO}"
   exit
else
   # countdown 10 secs before starting the dump
   echo
   for ((i=10; i>=0; i--)); do
      # echo "   ${DUMPDIR} has $(df -h ${DUMPDIR} | tail -1 | awk {'print $4'}) of free space. taking a dump in $i seconds"
      echo "   ${DUMPDIR} has $(df -h ${DUMPDIR} | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}') GiB of free space. taking a dump in $i seconds"
      sleep 1s
   done
   sleep 10s

   # get the dumb of ${DBNAME} from ${SOURCE}
   nice pg_dump -h "${SOURCE}" -d "${DB_NAME}" -U "${DB_USER}" -v -Fd -j 2 \
   -f "${DUMPDIR}"/"${DUMPFILE}"_"${NOW}" >>  "${DUMPDIR}"/"${DUMPFILE}"_"${NOW}".out 2>&1
fi

# save return code into variable
RC=$?
export RC

# send mail for error or sucess
if [ $RC -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "ERROR: LaFIS_Dump_Erstellung_Ref ${DB_NAME} ist nicht fehlerfrei gelaufen" | \
   mailx -s [postgres@"$HOSTNAME"]: ERROR: LaFIS_Dump_Erstellung_Ref "${EMAIL_TO}"
   exit 1
else
   echo "SUCCESS: LaFIS_Dump_Erstellung_Ref ${DB_NAME} ist fertig" | \
   mailx -s [postgres@"$HOSTNAME"]: SUCCESS: LaFIS_Dump_Erstellung_Ref "${EMAIL_TO}"
fi
exit 0
```

This works until sending emails for succes or failure at the end (following the if..else section).

**EDIT:** The pg _dump is executed (apparantly successful), but no mail is being send.

Any idea what is going wrong there? The mailx command at the beginning works, so I think the problem lies in not proceeding to the final if..else.

Comment: You really don't want to use CAPS for shell variable names. Since, [by convention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/1081936), global environment variables are capitalized, it is bad practice to also use caps for your own, local variables because this can lead to naming collisions and hard to find bugs.

Comment: Embedding the countdown and invocation of pg_dump within the "else" branch of the "if" statement is redundant since there is an explicit "exit" if there is not enough free space. This is also potentially causing issues with the value of $RC. "This works until" is not a meaningful diagnostic - tell us what DID happen.

Comment: you mean I could just remove the `else` and `fi` aroung the pg_dump right? @symcbean

Comment: You could remove the 'fi' then replace 'else' with 'fi' - since you still to end the 'if' block.

Comment: It could be helpfull for debugging to call your script with `bash -x <yourscript>`

Comment: It'd be helpful if you'd tell what kind of an issue you're seeing. It works until X, but then what happens? Observing the result might point directly to the root of the problem, but having everyone read your code with a fine comb or modify it enough to be able to test it may make it harder or slower for you to get answers

Comment: added some more info ... pg_dump runs, just no mail is being send. I'll try again tonight without the else and report back. thx for the pointers thus far and sorry if my initial post was not clear enough.

Comment: If the issue is about sending emails based on a condition, can you write a simpler script that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Have you put the script into https://www.shellcheck.net/ ? If not, try that and see what it advises

Answer (score 0):

I see a few potential issues:

1. <s>`RC` will always be zero because it reports that the preceding `if` was successful, not the outcome of the last command inside the `if` subclauses (which I guess is what you want)</s>
2. Did you mean to export `RC`? Is that required?
3. `$HOSTNAME` does not need to be quoted inside the subject, because it is not permitted for hostnames to have spaces.
4. The subject text following `mailx -s` should be fully quoted, e.g. `mailx -s "[postgres@$HOSTNAME]: SUCCESS: LaFIS_Dump_Erstellung_Ref" "${EMAIL_TO}"`
5. (My `mailx` is aliased to GNU `mail.mailutils` and doesn't work with the syntax you are using)

Comment: 1., no it won't, the exit status of an `if` is that of the last command executed (within the `then` or `else` lists), _unless_ nothing is executed, in which case it's zero. Try e.g. `if true; then (exit 123); fi; echo $?` vs. `if false; then (exit 123); fi; echo $?`, or closer to the one here, `if false; then true; else (exit 123); fi; echo $?`. It might be clearer to capture the exit status right after the command, sure, but the exit status is still available after the `then` or `else` branch closes. (Though you won't know which command it was, except here since it won't be the `exit`)

Comment: 2. does it matter? 3. `$HOSTNAME` can contain anything. Try e.g. `HOSTNAME='foo * bar'` and then `echo $HOSTNAME`. 4. Isn't this in part contradicting the previous point? 5. Yes, annoyingly there's a couple of slightly incompatible implementations of `mail`, e.g. Debian has the GNU one you refer to, but also bsd-mailx at least.

Comment: @ilkkachu 1. thanks, yes I learned something. 2. No it doesn't matter it was an observation 3. $HOSTNAME is usually (on systems I have used) predefined as the host name, which should not have spaces, but of course you *can* set it to anything you like 4. and I mentioned not quoting $HOSTNAME because then OP does not have to escape quotes when quoting the *whole* subject.

Comment: Yes, that's what `HOSTNAME` is _likely_ to be, but if you just quote it like any other expansion, you don't need to think or care if it really is that in all cases, or if some joker can sneak in a less nice value. It should probably be quoted as `"[postgres@${HOSTNAME}]:"`, so that the quotes protect the glob characters and the variable at the same go, no need to escape anything.